# Half parabola- $y = x^2$ - does the derivative exist at x = 0?

Tags: calculus, limits, conic-sections

If we took $y = x^2$ and cut it in half by letting $x\ge 0$, does the derivative still exist at $x = 0$ or is it $\text{DNE}$?

I think it's still $0$ because the function and it's derivative are both still continuous. However, my friends have told me that it's $\text{DNE}$ for the simple reason that the left and right limits at $x = 0$ don't exist. I don't understand this logic.

Is $y = x^2, x \ge 0$ differentiable at $x = 0$?

Comment: Are you asking if the function $f\colon [0, +\infty[, x\mapsto x^2$ is differentiable at $0$? The answer is yes. At first the derivative is only defined for interior points, but this is extendable to the extreme points by considering only the appropriate lateral limits.

Comment: Yes, the right hand derivitive will still exist.

Answer (score 3):

when you cut off the parabola, you cut off half the tangent at $x = 0, y = 0$ with it. so what remains is half the tangent. there is definition of one sided derivative at the boundaries of the domain. for example, at the left boundary $x = a,$ the one sided derivative of $f$ is defined by $$D_+f|_{x = a} = \lim_{x \to a+} = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}.$$

likewise, you can define $D_-f|_{x = b}$ at the right end point $b.$

Comment: So only the one-sided derivative exists? or both sides exist?

Comment: if you have $y = x^2, x \ge 0,$ then only the right hand derivative exists at $x = 0.$ at an interior point all three will have the same value.